# PHP - Get CPT taxonomy, show taxonomy color from ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm using the WP Job Manager plugin for Wordpress which essentially is built upon a custom post type. It has categories enabled and I have assigned a color to each category.

I can get the color to show by using something like:

```
<div style="background-color:<?php the_field('job_category_colour', 'category_54'); ?>; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
```

But this isn't great as I'm adding this code to the single.php page so I need it to be dynamic enough to check for the category of the post first and then apply the color of that post.

I can pull through a list of categories by using this:

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'job_listing_category'); ?>
```

So, I think I somehow have to combine the two - This is where I'm getting stuck...

It essentially needs to say;

'get category'

'get color of that category'

'apply that colour as a background color to the div'

I have tried the following in various formats:

```
style="background-color:<?php the_field('job_category_colour', '$post->ID, 'job_listing_category''); ?>; height: 100px; width: 100px;"
```

But I can't seem to get it all working correctly. Any help or advice will be massively appreciated - Thanks for looking! :)

Comment: You forgot single quote in post id '$post->ID' and also job_listing_category has extra single quote remove that.

Comment: Thanks dipmala - do you mean like this: <div style="background-color:<?php the_field('job_category_colour', '$post->ID', 'job_listing_category'); ?>; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div> - As thats still not working...

Comment: You need to get first taxonomy and then use that id in the_field

Comment: I know, that's what I can't seem to do, hence the original post :)

Comment: check @shaun answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check below code for the same.

```
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'job_listing_category', array("fields" => "all"));
    $currentcolor='';
    foreach($term_list as $term_single) 
    {
        $termid= $term_single->term_id; 
        $colorvalue= get_field('job_category_colour',  'category_' . $termid);
        if($colorvalue!='')  $currentcolor =$colorvalue;
    }


    style="background-color:<?php echo $currentcolor ; ?>; height: 100px; width: 100px;"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, dipmala! This works perfectly! However, if the post has more than one category assigned to it, it won't work, but that's kind of a design / organisational issue, to be honest - Thanks again!!